# Is it possible to write an audio file directly from Ruby?

Tags: ruby, audio

While I am sure that Ruby is not fast enough to do real time audio, I wonder if there is a way to write audio arrays directly in ruby, and mix these down to a wav/aiff format. I suspect that there is a problem with this method (too slow perhaps?) because I have never seen an implementation.

Comment: What do you mean by "directly"?

Comment: Take a function, like a sine wave, and write it directly to an array, and output as a .wav. No actual playback necessary in this case.

Comment: Of course you can, if your willing to write all of the code down to the byte handling yourself, and you have the expertise.

Comment: "not fast enough" is a bad start for a Ruby question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the `raiff` gem to do this, although I would have preferred `sndfile` https://github.com/ronen/sndfile or `ruby-audio` https://github.com/fugalh/ruby-audio if it wasn't for trouble with dependencies on the Mac. The latter works with `narray` for handling audio sample data, which is quite speedy, and if you are feeling advanced then you can also play with frequency-domain processing using `fftw3`

Also, for an implementation of a Ruby drum machine, take a look at "beats": https://github.com/jstrait/beats

Comment: Did you just google it up, or do you actually do music in Ruby?

Comment: @Boris Stitnicky: Neither. Too complex to explain in detail. But most recently, I've used `raiff`, `narray` and `fftw3` along with `ruby-fann` to get a credible result in a kaggle competition: http://www.kaggle.com/c/whale-detection-challenge (I am 17th on leaderboard, which is in top 10%)

Comment: Uh oh, competitions. I'd like to see your algorithm, but it is nowhere to be seen on kaggle.

Comment: @Boris Stitnicky: Here's the main spectrogram generation class, which is vaguely relevant to the question: https://gist.github.com/neilslater/5476045 - the machine learning stuff is far too messy to share I'm afraid (and I'm about 20 years behind, still using basic neural nets in any case!)